# Android phonegap show image from external with handlebar

Tags: android, image, templates, cordova

Im Trying show an image from web (external) with handlebar template

in my arq.handlebars I have this:

```
< img src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/system/products/avatars/034/thumb/image.jpg" data-rel="external"/ >
```

I also tried so:

```
< a class="imagem" style="background-image: url(http://127.0.0.1:3000/system/products/avatars/034/thumb/image.jpg);" data-rel="external" />
```

But it is not working. what appears is me: [?] (an icon like this)

Answer (score 1):

Where did this path come from?  Unless you're running something on your phone on Port 3000 this isn't going to work.  The correct path in Cordova file:///android_asset/www/ assuming that you put your code in the assets/www directory of your project.

Either that or find out where the actual image is coming from and replace the path with the address of that server.

Comment: Oh, yes. I have a server running in port 3000...

I was so simulating a web link. but it can also be something like: 
< img src=" http://images.wikia.com/wikia/pt-br/images/5/5c/Lupa.gif" data-rel="external"/ >

Comment: But is the server running on the phone, or on your dev box?